# Routing between pages with <Switch> & <Redirect> returns the home page - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My target at this assignment is to redirect a page to the next one . Basically when user scans membership card there has to appear a pop-up that notifies him that everything is "OK" and Redirect him to the next page . Until now i get the state of the scan and the pop-up appears , but it wont redirect me to the next page . I wonder what should i do to fix that problem ? Here is my code until now :

**Modules**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router'
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import BarcodeReader from 'react-barcode-reader';
import SPage from '../pages/SelectionPage'
```

**HomeJS.js** ***- my function with the timeout***

```
class Home extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      okRedirect: true,
      modalOK: false
    }
    this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this)
  }

  handleScan(data) {
    console.log('barcode is' + data);
    this.setState({
      modalOK: true
    })

    setTimeout( function() {
      console.log('setTimeOut OK');
      this.setState({ okRedirect: true });
      console.log('state redirect: ' + this.state.okRedirect);

    }.bind(this) , 3000)
  }
```

**HomeJS.js** *** - the rest of the code***

```
 render() {
    return (

      <Router>
        <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" render={() => (this.state.okRedirect? (
          <Redirect to="/SPage" component={SPage}/>
            ) : (
        <Route exact path='/'/>
        )
      )}/>
        <div className='home'>
          <div>
            <BarcodeReader
              onError={this.handleError}
              onScan={this.handleScan}
            />
            <p>{this.state.result}</p>
               ...
         </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Comment: You can simply use `<Redirect to="/SPage" component={SPage}/>` without englobing it inside `<Router>`

Comment: not actually , because `<Redirect/>` has to be inside of `<Router/>` to work

Comment: `<Router>` should englobe your whole application. The `<Redirect />` does not have to be inside a switch and in the render of a route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually is not nesscecary to use `<Redirect/>` . The simple answer to my question is :

```
class Home extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      okRedirect: false,
      modalOK: false
    }

    this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this)
  }

  handleScan(data) {

    this.setState({
      modalOK: true
    })

    setTimeout( function() {

      this.setState({ okRedirect: true });


    }.bind(this) , 3000)
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.okRedirect) {
      console.log('State is changed');
      return (

        <SelectionPage/>
      );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Redirect` use `Route` to go to your desired page.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (this.state.okRedirect &&
          <Route path="/SPage" component={SPage}/>) }/>
```

or you may define your `Route` for `/SPage` and do the `Redirect`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't resolve my problem . Still i have the scan option but it doesn't redirect me to the next page .